# opencv C++ negative X,Y cordinates from detections (yolo detections)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using Yolo detection algorithm to predict bounding boxes, but the detection returns some values as negative integers , but the `cv::rectangle` function draws correct rectangles on to images, so it's kind of puzzling why there are negative or even long values in the detection coordinates, here `get_rect` function returns x,y,width,height, after applying NMS

```
std::vector<uint> rr = get_rect(img, res[j].bbox);
```

later converted it into opencv understandable format:

```
cv::Rect r = cv::Rect(rr[0],rr[1],rr[2],rr[3]);
```

when print following values of `Rect r` some values are ambiguous,

```
r.x = 398
r.y = 1431655936
r.width = 22
r.height = -1431655867
```

As can be seen values of y coordinate and height are completely out of the canvas, so any reasons for this.

Also , i made sure that the input image dimensions , infering dimensions , and output image rendering dimensions all are same, Also `cv::rectangle` function correctly drawing all the rectangles with there respective object locations.

Comment: use `int`, not `uint`: `std::vector<int> `

Comment: @Miki , still same issue

Comment: Does tis problem occur when the rectangle tries to draw on borders of window? Or this happens even it draws inside of the window?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, good point made, i need to simulate environment for this. Thanks