# opencv draw rectangle function behaves different in C++ , python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am getting bounding boxes from Yolo implementation in C++, the detected bounding boxes draws correctly using `cv::Rectangle` function in C++, but when drawed same bounding box coordinates in python it's localising objects incorrectly,

C++ `cv::Rectangle` function output,

[image: C++ image rendering with correct bounding boxes]

Python `cv2.rectangle` method output,

[image: python image rendering with incorrect bounding boxes]

I also made sure that the aspect ratio for both the input image is same for python and C++, ***in order to utilise(draw) detected bounded boxes in python i first dumped it to json file from the c++ detection module(yolo), and then read and rendered in separate python script just to render image and show bounding boxes using*** `cv2.Rectangle`

Comment: Looks like the second image interprets height and width values as coordinates.

Comment: could you please elaborate, more

Comment: Can you print the raw `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`. Looking at the result your `(x1, y1)` are correct but `(x2, y2)` have become corrupted and also negative. Can you share your drawing code?

Comment: @MilindDeore, i have pointed out this issue in separate question please look at it, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62956474/1632479

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to conclusion that, `cv::Rectangle` function takes , offset values for width and height arguments , so suppose

```
rect = cv::Rect(x,y,w_offset,h_offset)
cv::rectangle(img, rect, cv::Scalar(0x27, 0xC1, 0x36), 2);
```

c++ implementation for `cv::rectangle` function internally manages offset values with there respective ending (x,y) bounding box coordinates, but for python based implementation offset values needs to be explicitly sum up with starting (x,y) values of the bounding boxes,

```
c1, c2 = (x ,y), ((x+w_offset), (y+h_offset))
cv2.rectangle(img, c1, c2, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Answer (score 0):

For record. I faced the very same problem and the solution was to use **Scaler(0,255,255)** I was using wrong value.

```
bbox_2d = cv::selectROI(frame, false); 
// Display bounding box. 
cv::rectangle(frame, bbox_2d, cv::Scalar( 0,255,255 ), 2, 1 ); 
cv::imshow("Tracking", frame);
```